# Azure function app managed identity log analytics

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I’m wondering if it’s possible to use managed identity in order to authenticate with an azure log analytics workspace. My setup is as follows:
Windows function app with powershell core.
Event grid
Log analytics workspace

In a simple setup i was able to push all the messages from event grid to log analytics via the function app. I was able to do this by using the workspace ID and a shared key but as you might imagine  this is not desirable for a production scenario so I’m investing the authentication via managed identities.

I’ve created a managed identity and gave it permission to the desired log analytics workspace but I have no idea how to write the powershell code in order to make use of the identity and unfortunately I’m not getting any further with Google.

thanks in advance!

Reading Microsoft documents, scouring the Internet, trying different sort of code solutions but alas no solution found.

I want to connect to log analytics with function apps via managed identity in powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Log Analytics agents use a workspace key as an enrollment key to verify initial access and provision a certificate further used to establish a secure connection between the agent and Azure Monitor.

You can opt out of local authentication and ensure that only telemetry that's exclusively authenticated by using Managed Identities and Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) is ingested into Azure Monitor.

To enable Azure AD integration for Azure Monitor Logs and remove reliance on these shared secrets:

1. Migrate to Azure Monitor Agent from the Log Analytics agents. Azure
   Monitor Agent doesn't require any keys but instead requires a
   system-managed identity.
   You probably don't use monitor agent so you can skip this step.
2. Disable local authentication for Log
   Analytics workspaces.
3. Ensure that only authenticated telemetry is
   ingested in your Application Insights resources with Azure AD
   authentication for Application Insights (preview).

The DisableLocalAuth property is used to disable any local authentication on your Log Analytics workspace. When set to true, this property enforces that Azure AD authentication must be used for all access.

Use the following PowerShell commands to disable local authentication:

```
    $workspaceSubscriptionId = "[You subscription ID]"
    $workspaceResourceGroup = "[You resource group]"
    $workspaceName = "[Your workspace name]"
    $disableLocalAuth = $false
    
    # login
    Connect-AzAccount
    
    # select subscription
    Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $workspaceSubscriptionId
    
    # get private link workspace resource
    $workspace = Get-AzResource -ResourceType Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces -ResourceGroupName $workspaceResourceGroup -ResourceName $workspaceName -ApiVersion "2021-06-01"
    
    # set DisableLocalAuth
    $workspace.Properties.Features | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DisableLocalAuth -Value $disableLocalAuth -Force
    $workspace | Set-AzResource -Force
```

To authenticate MI in LAW you need to make sure it has proper role assigned, at least [Log Analytics Reader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#log-analytics-reader)

After which you should be able to auth using AAD. There are multiple ways to do so but using Powershell you are typically interested in something like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71067772/accessing-azure-ad-using-a-managed-identity).