# Errors using Azure Managed Identity to connect to Azure Automation from VS Code

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-managed-identity

About 8 months ago I built several automation runbooks that successfully run using a System-Assigned Managed Identity. I used this code excerpt from this thread, [Accessing Azure AD using a Managed Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71067772/accessing-azure-ad-using-a-managed-identity) to connect to Azure AD using the Managed Identity. This code works perfectly when executed from the Azure Automation portal.

```
Connect-azaccount -identity
$context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
$graphToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com").AccessToken
$aadToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.windows.net").AccessToken
Write-Output "Hi I'm $($context.Account.Id)"
Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $aadToken -AccountId $context.Account.Id -TenantId $context.tenant.id | out-null
Write-Output "Success!`n"
```

Due to the impending deprecation of the AzureAD PowerShell module, I am in the process of converting the scripts to use Microsoft Graph vs AzureAD. I have recently installed the Azure Automation extension in VS Code to edit the Runbooks. When I test a runbook in VSC, it fails because it's not able to get a token. I get this error,

```
Connect-azaccount -identity
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint.
```

Looking at the Managed Identity IAM properties in Azure, I am the Owner and User Access Administrator. There are no Deny Assignments to the identity. How can I allow VSC on my local machine to get a token from the Managed Identity to run the Runbook? Is there a better way? Using Graph, perhaps?

Thank you for your time.

P.S. I reviewed the 2 questions Stack Overflow presented before posting. The first did not correspond to my problem, and the second was regarding User-Assigned Managed Identities, not System-assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because a system-assigned managed identity cannot be used locally ([same is true for a user-assigned managed identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67845857/can-a-user-assigned-managed-identity-be-used-locally)). It can only be used in Azure.

A system-assigned managed identity is an identity (basically an Entra ID user) assigned to an Azure resource. From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview#managed-identity-types):

[image]